# Why is an async pipe which is subscribed to a merged observable is overriding the previously emitted value?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have an observable which is merged from two observables. I am using this observable to pass it through the async pipe to a child component. When the two inner observables emit, the last emitted values are being overridden by the newer values.

```
let a = new Subject();
let b = new Subject();
this.loaderData$ = merge(a.asObservable(), b.asObservable())
setTimeout(() => {
    b.next(2);
    a.next(1);
}, 1000)

let a = new Subject();
let b = new Subject();
this.loaderData$ = merge(a.asObservable(), b.asObservable())
setTimeout(() => {
    b.next(2);
    setTimeout(() => { a.next(1) }, 1000)
}, 1000)

html:

<ts-loader [loaderData]="loaderData$ | async"></ts-loader>

@Component({
  selector: 'ts-loader',
  templateUrl: './ts-loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ts-loader.component.scss']
})
export class TsLoaderComponent {

  @Input()
  set loaderData(loaderData:any){
    console.log(loaderData)
}
```

The observable loaderData$ is passed to the child component through an async pipe. But the first piece of code inputs only 1 to be child component, whereas the second piece of code inputs both 1 and 2.

I am not able to figure out why are these observables working like this.

ps: I have a workaround to subscribe to the observable inside the child component and get the expected results. But I wanted to make it work with async pipes.

Comment: [Both do the same thing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfn5kj). If not, please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Yup thats behaving the same, as you are putting the observable output on same div. Its not visible. Instead put some delay on the inner setTimeout.. The difference can be noticed

Comment: This is your exact code. Again, if not, please provide a [mcve]. I gave you the courtesy of making a sandbox (and trust me I don't do it often), now **YOU** must do it. I'm not a psychic, I can't just guess why it doesn't work on your side.

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Answer (score 0):

It probably did happened already in your async pipe, async pipe only renders the latest result to screen so your 1 is overwriting 2. In order to test out place a `tap`

```
let a = new Subject();
let b = new Subject();
this.loaderData$ = merge(a.asObservable(), b.asObservable()).pipe(tap(console.log))

setTimeout(() => {
    b.next(2);
    a.next(1);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: I dont think so, I have edited my code with the loaderComponent. I am doing a console log inside the component. But could'nt see both the values :( .... But my second piece of code for merge works fine..

Comment: Yes with subscribe it works, Wanted to know why this doesn’t with async pipe

Comment: could you add the timeout to 2000 and see if async pipe works?

Comment: Tried that too.. no luck!

Comment: Yes, when i tap it I could see it emitting, but when i check it inside loader component, i couldnt see it

Comment: Subject doesn’t save last emitted value. , async pipe has to be there Before it emits. If u tap and can log the result means code is working properly